# Angular 5 HttpClient: mapping json object array to my object array

Tags: angular, angular5

Using Angular 5 with the HttpClient, I have seen examples of something like:

```
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
```

I am trying to understand the many ways of achieving mapping the JSON array of users to my User array.

Does Angular know how to map the data as above, or do I have to perform the .map function to build the User array myself?

Comment: If you are using the generic method you don't need to map. Just subscribe and get your parsed data.

Comment: Thank you! yes makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

you can do simply

```
getUsers() {
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

if your response is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "example2",
  }
]
```

then you can do this:

```
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.arrayUsers = result;
  }
)
```

else if you have it deeper in your JSON:

```
{
  "success":[
    {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "example1",
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "example2",
    }
 ]
```

}

then you should do in this way:

```
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.arrayUsers = result['success']; 
  }
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for confirming that.  I realised afterwards that I was trying to do something like automapper in the .NET world i.e. if the JSON result had more fields than I wanted, I just thought the this.http.get<User[]> would map only the data from the JSON to my User array.

I have since seen some deserialisation examples which seem to do that - I am just trying to find the most efficient way.

Many thanks for responding!